# Two tables are listed in sequence but how they are linked?

Tags: sql

I have this query for selecting `currentstock`.

I think

```
(SELECT ItemName, SUM(Quantity) AS t1 
 FROM INVENTORYINDETAIL 
 WHERE TransType = 'PROC' 
   AND TransDate <= @TransDate 
   AND FacilityCode = @FacilityCode   
 GROUP BY ItemName)
```

is a table but there is another table `INVENTORYINDETAIL` immediately after that.

The two tables are listed in sequence so I don't understand how they are linked.

Can you explain each of these queries?

```
DECLARE @TransDate VARCHAR(10),
        @FacilityCode VARCHAR(5)

SET @TransDate = '2019-09-19'
SET @FacilityCode = '10'

SELECT 
    INVENTORYINDETAIL.ItemName, (t1 - t2) AS CurrentStock 
FROM
    (SELECT ItemName, SUM(Quantity) AS t1 
     FROM INVENTORYINDETAIL 
     WHERE TransType = 'PROC' 
       AND TransDate <= @TransDate 
       AND FacilityCode = @FacilityCode 
    GROUP BY ItemName) INVENTORYINDETAIL 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ItemName, SUM(Quantity) AS t2 
     FROM INVENTORYOUTDETAIL 
     WHERE OutType = 'PROC' 
     GROUP BY ItemName) INVENTORYOUTDETAIL ON INVENTORYINDETAIL.ItemName = INVENTORYOUTDETAIL.ItemName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single query here, which is making use of two sub-queries. I have edited the query with indenting to make it more obvious.

Basically you can create sub-query, and then treat that as though it were a table. So the part of the query:

```
from (
  SELECT ItemName,SUM(Quantity) as t1 
  from INVENTORYINDETAIL 
  WHERE TransType = 'PROC' and TransDate <= @TransDate and FacilityCode = @FacilityCode 
  group by ItemName
) INVENTORYINDETAIL
```

is running a query on the `INVENTORYINDETAIL` table, and then creating an alias of `INVENTORYINDETAIL` (could be any name), while the second part

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ItemName,SUM(Quantity) as t2 
  from INVENTORYOUTDETAIL 
  WHERE OutType = 'PROC' 
  group by ItemName
) INVENTORYOUTDETAIL on INVENTORYINDETAIL.ItemName = INVENTORYOUTDETAIL.ItemName
```

does a similar grouped query against `INVENTORYOUTDETAIL` and then joins its result to the first.

This type of query is generally used where you can't do any direct join between the tables, as it would result in a many-to-many join.